# Vue js table row with info

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to see information when I click to row in the table. I tried `@click`, `router:to` but it didn't help. Maybe I should try to make list item instead of data-table?

html code:

```
<v-data-table  v-scroll:#scroll-target="onScroll"
  :items-per-page="-1"
  hide-default-footer
  dense
  :headers="headers"
  :items="companies"
  item-key="name"
  class="elevation-1"
></v-data-table>
```

Vue code below:

```
<script>
   export default {
    data: () => ({
companies: [
  {
    name: "Company",
    status: "Active"
  },
  {
    name: "Company2",
    status: "Active"
  },
  {
    name: "Company3",
    status: "Active"
  },  
 ],
     headers: [
  {
    text: "Company name",
    align: "start",
    sortable: false,
    value: "name"
             },
  { text: "Status", value: "status" }
],
methods: {
  onScroll (e) {
    this.companies = e.target.scrollTop
  },
}
})
};
 </script>
```

I am using vuetify library. Maybe this is a problem of vuetify and it has different command to make clickeble row in data-table?

Comment: `I want to see information when I click to row in the table`... what information? Where?

Comment: Any information. For example just a simple text right to the table

Comment: Where do you want it displayed?

Comment: Sorry for long answer. Right to data-table

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the vuetify data table events: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/

The first one there is `click:row`.

So you would have something like:

```
// template
<v-data-table @click:row="rowClicked"></v-data-table>
```

```
// script
export default {
    methods: {
        rowClicked (item) {
            // show something or do your router stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.